# Anaconda: not explainable behaviour of packages installed through conda pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to export a conda env built using conda + pip (installed through conda), but I'm missing some of the packages I have installed through pip. Below the details of the process I have followed.

The OS I'm running on is:

```
bdauser@testsuselinux:~> cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12-SP3"
VERSION_ID="12.3"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp3"
```

This is my anaconda version:

```
bdauser@testsuselinux:~> conda list anaconda
# packages in environment at /home/bdauser/anaconda3:
#
anaconda                  5.0.1            py36hd30a520_1
anaconda-client           1.6.5            py36h19c0dcd_0
anaconda-navigator        1.6.9            py36h11ddaaa_0
anaconda-project          0.8.0            py36h29abdf5_0
```

I have created and activated the anaconda env through:

```
bdauser@testsuselinux:~> conda create --name libmad python=3.5
bdauser@testsuselinux:~> source activate libmad
```

I then have installed pip for conda through:

```
(libmad) bdauser@testsuselinux:~> conda install pip
```

I then successfully installed a package using pip for conda:

```
(libmad) bdauser@testsuselinux:~> /home/bdauser/anaconda3/envs/libmad/bin/pip install nltk==3.4
```

I have checked if the package is actually installed through:

```
(libmad) bdauser@testsuselinux:~/anaconda3/envs/libmad/bin> /home/bdauser/anaconda3/envs/libmad/bin/pip install nltk==3.4
Requirement already satisfied: nltk==3.4 in /home/bdauser/anaconda3/envs/libmad/lib/python3.5/site-packages (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/bdauser/anaconda3/envs/libmad/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from nltk==3.4) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /home/bdauser/anaconda3/envs/libmad/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from nltk==3.4) (3.4.0.3)
```

At this point I have tried to export the conda env:

```
(libmad) bdauser@testsuselinux:~/anaconda3/envs/libmad/bin> conda env export
name: libmad
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- ca-certificates=2019.1.23=0
- certifi=2018.8.24=py35_1
- libedit=3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
- libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
- libgcc-ng=8.2.0=hdf63c60_1
- libstdcxx-ng=8.2.0=hdf63c60_1
- ncurses=6.1=he6710b0_1
- openssl=1.0.2r=h7b6447c_0
- pip=10.0.1=py35_0
- python=3.5.6=hc3d631a_0
- readline=7.0=h7b6447c_5
- setuptools=40.2.0=py35_0
- sqlite=3.28.0=h7b6447c_0
- tk=8.6.8=hbc83047_0
- wheel=0.31.1=py35_0
- xz=5.2.4=h14c3975_4
- zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
prefix: /home/bdauser/anaconda3/envs/libmad
```

But nltk does not show up as you can see.

I tried to run a simple `conda list` and I can see the nltk package:

```
(libmad) bdauser@testsuselinux:~/anaconda3/envs/libmad/bin> conda list
# packages in environment at /home/bdauser/anaconda3/envs/libmad:
#
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0
certifi                   2018.8.24                py35_1
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1
nltk                      3.4                       <pip>
openssl                   1.0.2r               h7b6447c_0
pip                       10.0.1                   py35_0
pip                       19.1.1                    <pip>
python                    3.5.6                hc3d631a_0
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5
setuptools                41.0.1                    <pip>
setuptools                40.2.0                   py35_0
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                   <pip>
six                       1.12.0                    <pip>
sqlite                    3.28.0               h7b6447c_0
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0
wheel                     0.31.1                   py35_0
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

If I run the same command with the export flag, I don't see nltk again:

```
(libmad) bdauser@testsuselinux:~/anaconda3/envs/libmad/bin> conda list --export
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
ca-certificates=2019.1.23=0
certifi=2018.8.24=py35_1
libedit=3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
libgcc-ng=8.2.0=hdf63c60_1
libstdcxx-ng=8.2.0=hdf63c60_1
ncurses=6.1=he6710b0_1
openssl=1.0.2r=h7b6447c_0
pip=10.0.1=py35_0
python=3.5.6=hc3d631a_0
readline=7.0=h7b6447c_5
setuptools=40.2.0=py35_0
sqlite=3.28.0=h7b6447c_0
tk=8.6.8=hbc83047_0
wheel=0.31.1=py35_0
xz=5.2.4=h14c3975_4
zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour? What am I doing wrong here? The goal is to export the conda env to another machine with all the packages installed through pip.

Thanks in advance, 
Alessio

Comment: I think you've left something crucial out: How did you get `pip=19.1.1` in there? There is no build of that version for Python 3.5 on Anaconda cloud. I suspect you need to stick to the `pip` installed through Conda in order for installs through PyPI to be recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you updated `pip` through PyPI and then used that to install your package.  I think Conda has issues recognizing packages not installed through the Conda-installed pip. Instead, try using only `pip` installed through Conda:

```
conda create -n libmad python=3.5 pip
conda activate libmad
pip install nltk==3.4
```

<sub>**Tip:** You don't have to provide a full path to `pip` if you're in the activated environment.</sub>

Technically, we shouldn't have to include `pip` in the create step, because Conda always installs `pip` whenever `python` is installed; we'll leave it here for good measure.  Also note, that you can get newer versions of `pip` through the Conda Forge channel (up to 18.0 for Python 3.5).

Then, `conda env export` gives:

```
name: libmad
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - ca-certificates=2019.1.23=0
  - certifi=2018.8.24=py35_1
  - libcxx=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libcxxabi=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libedit=3.1.20181209=hb402a30_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=1
  - ncurses=6.1=h0a44026_1
  - openssl=1.0.2r=h1de35cc_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py35_0
  - python=3.5.6=hc167b69_0
  - readline=7.0=h1de35cc_5
  - setuptools=40.2.0=py35_0
  - sqlite=3.28.0=ha441bb4_0
  - tk=8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - wheel=0.31.1=py35_0
  - xz=5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - zlib=1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
  - pip:
    - nltk==3.4
    - singledispatch==3.4.0.3
    - six==1.12.0
```

Comment: Thanks @merv So the command I ran in the 4th block of code I posted (conda install pip) is somewhat wrong?

Comment: I get a PackageNotFoundError if I try to create the env with conda-forge::pip. 
Instead if I create the env without it and I do not install pip through conda install pip, I can see nltk within my  conda env. Thanks @merv!

Comment: @AlessioG Okay, I adjusted it to remove the Conda Forge part - I only had that in there because you can get more recent versions of `pip` through there, but it isn't necessary. To be clearer, none of the commands you reported were wrong.  Nevertheless, somehow you wound up with two versions of `pip` in your env, and the one was incompatible.